# How to SetSource to mediaElement in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I want to use this API  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br244338.aspx

but it has got this requirements:**Minimum supported phone
 Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Runtime apps only]**

My phone is wp8.1 and I am developing using wp silverlight 8.1.

Please what is the equivalent in wpSilverlight8.1?

I tried using PickSingleFileAndContinue() and it works fine until I get the video but I dont know how to get the stream in order to get the stream to assign to my mediaElement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it and it work!

```
    public async void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        StorageFile file = args.Files[0];

        if (file.Name.EndsWith("mp4")) {
            IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            mediaControl.SetSource(fileStream, file.ContentType);
        ...
        }
```

got ideas from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642086(v=vs.105).aspx